# How to program a sandboxed application in Yosemite

Tags: osx-yosemite, sandbox

I was trying to program a simple TODO app for Yosemite with sandboxing. Apple has its tutorials for the  same but they are not very elaborate. I wanted to know sandbox APIs like `sandbox_init()` and APIs for console logs (heard sandboxed apps use some special APIs). Could someone please point me to some open source app with sandboxing on Yosemite, so that I could see the APIs that it is using.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `sandbox_init()` etc. in order to create a sandboxed app.

Roughly, you need to understand:

1. Use the APIs to find *well known directories* and don't assume that `/Users/username/Documents` is the *Documents folder*, for example.
2. The app has no access to user files and must gain access via `NSOpenPanel`.
3. If the app wants to retain access it has already gained then it needs to create and store bookmark URLs, which can be reloaded during a later invocation.
4. If the sandboxed app spawns a child process, then that child process needs it's own set of entitlements.

Once you understand that it's normally just a case of setting *Use Sandbox* in the app capabilities and you're off.